# Java | GlobalScope

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь на Java реализовать GlobalScope. Пишу:

```
GlobalScope.launch();
```

И тут же мне выдает:

```
Cannot resolve method launch
```

Как мне правильно реализовать?

Подключал так:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.0.1"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь вызывать метод kotlin из java, поэтому я допускаю что для этого нужно добавить прослойку в зависимости:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8
```

Как сказано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52887677/9363441). Вот [документация](https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html)